# Can't Change Jetbrains Pycharm python interpreter from 3.6 to 2.7

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm, gae-python27

I'm using pycharm community edition for learning. and I need to change the project interpreter to 2.7. I have linux ubuntu 18.04 and I downloaded and installed python 2.7.15, but I just can't find the interpreter. Can anyone help with finding it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**File | Settings | Project Interpreter**

then click on show all to find the desired version 
you can also click on the existing python version then edit it to select the python version in your /user/bin  manually

Comment: well, thank you, but I'm using Linux so there areknow program files, and I also can't find it in the /user/bin folder..

Comment: did you install python2.7 in a correct way? you can type " whereis python2.7 " in the terminal to find the installation location